# problem with minipage

Tags: minipage

I would like to move outside the pic the second minipage (see the figure below).

[image]

This is the part of the code with "minipage"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{package}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\linespread{1.5}                

\frenchspacing 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}
   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
   \usepackage{lxfonts}
 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
   \fbox{%
     \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
       \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
       #2
     }%
   }%
   \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item   TEXT TEXT TEXT
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{img.pdf}
 \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item $ z$
\item $z^2$
\item $ z^3$
\item $ z$
\item $z^2$
\item $ z^3$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your code compilable. instead of `\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{img.pdf}` probably should be `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img.pdf}`.

Comment: Please post a full minimal example, instead of just a sniplet

Comment: @Zarko I wrote "\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img.pdf}". Now how can I enlarge the pic without having the same problem?

Comment: @ryuk To enlarge the image, make its minipage bigger, while making the other minipage smaller at the same time so that both their widths sums up to <= 1

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt]

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   TEXT TEXT TEXT  

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
\item $z$
\item $z^2$
\item $z^3$
\item $z$
\item $z^2$
\item $z^3$
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

to start new line with mini pages, you should insert empty line after item. also image should not be wider than `minipage` in which it is enclosed. if you like to have bigger image, than consider [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) comment. for example

```
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth} % <---
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth} % <---
    \begin{itemize}
\item $z$
\item $z^2$
\item $z^3$
\item $z$
\item $z^2$
\item $z^3$
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```